# How can I change <p> tag data dynamically after some defined time delay using javascript?

Tags: javascript, time, tags, delay, paragraph

I want to change only `<p>` tag contents using javascript after a defined time delay. For example a

```
<p>messages</p>
```

should change depending on the no. of new messages came. As

```
<p>messages(1)</p>
<p>messages(2)</p>
```

Comment: Where do these new message come from? How do you know they've arrived? I think that you don't really want a "time-delay" but should focus on tying the update into the code where the new messages are retrieved.

Comment: new messages are retrieved from the database using a JSP function that checks database for new messages.

Comment: Does the JSP function render some javascript the will update the page later or does it simply run each time the page is rendered.  Are you looking for a way to re-run the JSP function periodically?  If you want to update the page without a full request cycle, you'll need to use some AJAX to call back to the server.  It's in the AJAX callback that you'll want to update your text.

Comment: Ya @tvanfosson I want that a JSP function should be called after a defined time limit and it will return an integer value that will be appended to the <p> tag content -> messages.

Comment: But the JSP is executed server-side.  What you need is some javascript that runs periodically and calls a server method via AJAX to get the updated data.  The client has no way of running your JSP code (it doesn't even see it) directly.

Comment: Thanks really nice comment :) and can you suggest me something that can help me in doing this?? some code, tutorial or something..??

Comment: Look at the ajax tutorials on http://jquery.com

Comment: Aishwarya: When you say "a JSP function", do you mean that you have a `URL` where you can retrieve the number of messages?

Comment: ya and it may be a servlet also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write your `<p>` as:

```
<p class="messages">messages</p>
```

Your javascript:

```
function updateMessages() {
    var ps = document.getElementsByClassName("messages");
    for(var i = 0, len = ps.length; i < len; i++) {
        ps[i].innerHTML = "messages (" + messageCount + ")";
    }
}

setTimeout(updateMessages, 1000);
```

Where `1000` is the number of milliseconds to delay.

Or if you want to do it periodically every **15** seconds, you can use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(updateMessages, 15000);
```

**UPDATE:**

I see your comment above:

> new messages are retrieved from the database using a JSP function that checks database for new messages

In that case, I gather you want to retrieve that periodically, in effect polling that URL? If you already use a javascript framework, I suggest you look at their `AJAX` documentation.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` which doesn't have a `text()` method. Perhaps you meant to iterate over the `NodeList` or take the first item in it and assign to `textContent`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Linus and Chris but I want to call a JSP function that returns the no. of messages. How can I do that? I mean calling a JSP function using javascript??

Comment: Thanks Chris, I realized that after I had (incorrectly) rewritten my previous jQuery version. I have updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready({
 function updatePara() {        
      $('p').html('Content to set in para');
    }
 });

setTimeout(updatePara, no.of milisecond to delay);
```

jQuery make dom manipulation much easy :)
The above code changes content of all the paragraph, So better to give the desired paragragh `<p></p>` some call name then filter the para to update with those name i.e `$('p.classname').html('your content')` OR `$('.classname').html('Your content')`
jQuery is AWESOME !!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout function:

```
var delay = 1000; // 1 second
setTimeout(function() {
  var pNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (var i=0, length=pNodes.length; i < length; i++) {
    pNodes[i].innerHTML = pNodes[i].innerHTML+"("+ (i+1) +")";
  }
}, delay);
```

`getElementsByTagName` is used just for example. The way of retrieving pNodes depends on structure of your html code.

Comment: Thanks Molecule Man and can you tell me how can I call a JSP function that returns an INT value of no. of messages using javascript code???

Comment: @AishwaryaShivaPareek, sorry, I can't (not an expert on JSP).